# MySQli connection object

Tags: php, mysqli, connection, undefined

I have a problem. I need to get mysqli connection from my Database Class to Register Class. But it doesn´t work. I always get error like:

```
Call to undefined method Database::query() in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\registration\class_register.php on line 47
```

I probably need link that connection.. but I do not know how to do this.
I found some topics about that .. but nothing worked.
Thanks for help :)

class_register.php

```
 <?php

include "class_db.php";

class Register
{
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $passmd5;
    private $email;

    private $errors;
    private $token;

    private $link_mysqli;
    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->errors   =   array();
        $this->username =   $this->filter($_POST['uname']);
        $this->password =   $this->filter($_POST['upass']);
        $this->email    =   $this->filter($_POST['umail']);

        $this->token    =   $_POST['token'];

        $this->passmd5  =   md5($this->password);


        $this->link_mysqli = new Database();//instance of Database Class

    }

    public function process()
    {
      if($this->valid_token() && $this->valid_data())
        $this->register();

        return count($this->errors) ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public function filter($var)
    {
      return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9@.]/','',$var);
    }

    public function register()
    {
       $result = $this->link_mysqli->query("INSERT INTO users (username,password) VALUES ('$this->username', '$this->passmd5')");
        if($result->link_mysqli->affected_rows() < 1)
            $this->errors[] = 'Nemožno vytvoriť účet';
    }

    public function show_errors()
    {
        echo "<h3>Errors</h3>";
        foreach($this->errors as $key=>$value)
            echo $value.'<br>';

    }

    public function valid_data()
    {
        if(empty($this->username))
            $this->errors[] = 'Nesprávne uživateľské meno';
        if(empty($this->password))
            $this->errors[] = 'Nesprávne uživateľské heslo';
        if(empty($this->email) || !filter_var($this->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
            $this->errors[] = 'Nesprávny e-mail';

        return count($this->errors) ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public function valid_token()
    {
        if(!isset($_SESSION['token']) || $this->token != $_SESSION['token'])
            $this->errors[] = 'Nesprávna Relácia';

        return count($this->errors) ? 0 : 1;
    }
    function status() {
        return print_r($this,true);
    }


}


?>
```

class_db.php

```
<?php

class Database
{
    private $mysqli;

    private $db_host = "127.0.0.1";
    private $db_user = "register";
    private $db_pass = "159753";
    private $db_database = "registration";

    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass, $this->db_database);
       if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
         printf("Nastala chyba pripojenia s hláškou: %s", $mysqli->errno(), $mysqli->error());
         die();

       }
       return $this->mysqli;
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->mysqli->close();
    }

}


?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
     session_start();
     if(isset($_POST['register'])){
       include "class_register.php";

       $register = new Register();

       if($register->process())
            echo "Úspešne zaregistrovaný";
       else
            $register->show_errors();
     }
     $token = $_SESSION['token'] = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(),true));
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
   <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="uname">Meno:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="uname" name="uname" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="upass">Heslo:</label></td>
            <td><input type="password" id="upass" name="upass" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="umail">E-Mail:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="umail" name="umail" /></td>
        </tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
        <tr><td><input type="submit" name="register" value="Registrovať" /></td></tr>
   </table>




</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor does not return a value, it just instantiates an object. And in your `Register` class, the `$link_mysqli` is of the class `Database` and that class does not have a `query` method.

There are several ways to solve that problem like adding a `query` method to your `Database` class, making your `$mysqli` variable public (and use `$this->link_mysqli->mysqli->query()`), have your `Database` class extend `mysqli`, etc.

I normally instantiate a real database object that I pass to the constructor of the classes that need it (dependency injection).

Comment: Could you please give me some example (dependency injection)? Sorry I am only starting with OOP. Thank you